# React Not Being Detected By Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am following what I believe to be an outdated course on learning React. On the first tutorial, the contents of the html file are as follows:

```
<head>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/cjs/react.development.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js"></script>    
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<script type="text/babel">
    // Define a react component class
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({});

    // Ask react to render this class
    var element = React.createElement(HelloWorld);

    // Place the rendered element in the DOM
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.body);
</script>
```

When attempting to view the html file in the browser, I am given 3 errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at react.development.js:14

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at react-dom-server.browser.development.js:14 

Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
at <anonymous>:3:13
```

I have been searching Google and Stackoverflow and all mentions of Babel and React refer to Webpack setups or Rollup, et al. Is it possible for a simple page written this way to work without a build process? I have no idea what is wrong otherwise.

Comment: try including the babel `script` tag before the react ones

Comment: @JosanIracheta Thanks for the suggestion. I tried moving it to the top, but I get the same errors. I added the CDN for Requirejs, and that seems to fix these errors but then creates entirely new errors. I'm not 100% convinced this is doable in a browser at this point.